# Adobe AIR on iPhone

Tags: flash, air, adobe

I am using Flash CS5.5 to export an ipa file using "AIR for iOS". I have the .p12 and mobileprovision file from Apple. The certificate is registered for 2 different devices, 1 iPod and 1 iPhone. I have installed the application using the iTunes on ipod and it worked fine. But when I try to install it on iphone it gave me following error

"The app can not install on the Sameer's iPhone because it is not compatible with this iPhone"

I tried using testflight and got the following error

"This build was compiled for an architecture that this device doesn't support. Contact your developer to have them release a new build for your architecture"

My iPhone is 3G and using latest iOS which is 4.2 I believe and my iPod is using 4.3.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CS5.5 comes with Air 2.6, which has these iOS system requirements:

iPod Touch 3rd & 4th generation, iPhone 3GS, and iPhone 4 iPad

I don't think it supports 3G.  This also goes for Air 3.x.

cf. [Air 2.6 specs](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/890/cpsid_89099.html), [Air 3 specs](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had to go back to cs5 and publish with air 2.1 and all worked.